# equivalent of space character in xml root tag

Tags: xml

I want to have a xml root tag with a space character, but since the naming conventions do not allow spaces in xml tags, I want to pass something of equivalent to a space character to be passed as xml root tag.

Is that possible?

Comment: How about choosing a better root node name?

Comment: Hi Marc,
I take the root node as input into Flex and show a part of root node as the title of a chart. If the chart name has 2 words as its heading, I would want them to come from the xml. I'm looking not to do the parsing in the flex as it is a very generic file.

Comment: Since you appear to have the ability to change the XML data (i.e. wanting to rename the root node), why not just add an attribute on the root node that contains the title you want to use in your chart and have Flex pull the name from that instead?

Answer (score 1):

PascalCase, camelCase, or underscores are your best bets:

```
<underscores_are_valid>
    <camelCase>Data</camelCase>
    <PascalCase>More Data</PascalCase>
</underscores_are_valid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If an obvious means to distinguish words in the root node is that important, I'd use `<camelCase>` to name the element.